# VBA Code to block user input in a textbox in a form in access depending on what option is selected

Tags: vba

I am trying to build a form in access and I need to block user input into a text box if an option box is selected as no, I am ver inexperienced using VBA so has anyone got any ideas it'll be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should try Googling the key terms in your query first ('disable input' 'textbox', 'option box', 'vba', etc.) , then if something is not working, post it here. (p.s., not a downvoter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following statement in the AfterUpdate Event of the OptionBox:
`Me.TextBox.Enabled = Not Me.OptionBox.Value`